# How do I mock a urllib2 response when using a custom opener?

Tags: python, unit-testing, urllib2

I'm installing a custom urllib2 BaseHandler to deal with HTTP 304 responses (as per [here](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=122&thread=15024)), and this works fine. However, when testing my other methods, I use the method from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276689/how-do-i-unit-test-a-module-that-relies-on-urllib2), which works perfectly. However, since the method from the first answer overrides the  custom opener, I cant use it for testing. Is there an alternative approach?