# Can I "fake" a package (or at least a module) in python for testing purposes?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want to fake a package in python. I want to define something so that the code can do

```
from somefakepackage.morefakestuff import somethingfake
```

And somefakepackage is defined in code and so is everything below it. Is that possible? The reason for doing this is to trick my unittest that I got a package ( or as I said in the title, a module ) in the python path which actually is just something mocked up for this unittest.

Comment: The word you're looking for is ___mock___.  This question might help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295438

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Sure. Define a class, put the stuff you need inside that, assign the class to `sys.modules["classname"]`.

```
class fakemodule(object):

    @staticmethod
    def method(a, b):
        return a+b

import sys
sys.modules["package.module"] = fakemodule
```

You could also use a separate module (call it `fakemodule.py`):

```
import fakemodule, sys

sys.modules["package.module"] = fakemodule
```

Comment: One trick with this is to make sure to also insert a fake module for `package` with `__path__ = []` as a top-level attribute. Without that, the module hierarchy is incomplete, which may confusing some tools.

Comment: Just to add on. If you're importing a sub-module, e.g. `import a.b.c`, you may need to assign fake modules to
`sys.modules["a"]`, `sys.modules["a.b"]` and `sys.modules["a.b.c"]`

Answer (score 22):

Yes, you can make a fake module:

```
from types import ModuleType
m = ModuleType("fake_module")

import sys
sys.modules[m.__name__] = m

# some scripts may expect a file
# even though this file doesn't exist,
# it may be used by Python for in error messages or introspection.
m.__file__ = m.__name__ + ".py"

# Add a function
def my_function():
    return 10

m.my_function = my_function
```

Note, in this example its using an actual module (of `ModuleType`) since some
Python code may expect modules, (instead of a dummy class).

This can be made into a utility function:

```
def new_module(name, doc=None):
    import sys
    from types import ModuleType
    m = ModuleType(name, doc)
    m.__file__ = name + '.py'
    sys.modules[name] = m
    return m

print(new_module("fake_module", doc="doc string"))
```

Now other scripts can run:

```
import fake_module
```

Answer (score 8):

I took some of the ideas from the other answers and turned them into a Python decorator `@modulize` which converts a function into a module.  This module can then be imported as usual.  Here is an example.

```
@modulize('my_module')
def my_dummy_function(__name__):  # the function takes one parameter __name__
    # put module code here
    def my_function(s): 
        print(s, 'bar')

    # the function must return locals()
    return locals()

# import the module as usual
from my_module import my_function
my_function('foo') # foo bar
```

The code for the decorator is as follows

```
import sys
from types import ModuleType

class MockModule(ModuleType):
    def __init__(self, module_name, module_doc=None):
        ModuleType.__init__(self, module_name, module_doc)
        if '.' in module_name:
            package, module = module_name.rsplit('.', 1)
            get_mock_module(package).__path__ = []
            setattr(get_mock_module(package), module, self)

    def _initialize_(self, module_code):
        self.__dict__.update(module_code(self.__name__))
        self.__doc__ = module_code.__doc__

def get_mock_module(module_name):
    if module_name not in sys.modules:
        sys.modules[module_name] = MockModule(module_name)
    return sys.modules[module_name]

def modulize(module_name, dependencies=[]):
    for d in dependencies: get_mock_module(d)
    return get_mock_module(module_name)._initialize_
```

The project can be found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/jasonrute/modulize).  In particular, I created this for programming contests which only allow the contestant to submit a single `.py` file. This allows one to develop a project with multiple .py files and then combine them into one `.py` file at the end.

Comment: I can't get your examples to work at the point of `from my_module import my_function`. Simply doing `import my_module` does work. Is this specific to one python version or something?

Comment: @AlanSE While I designed this for Python 3, I just pasted the above code into a Python 2.7.10 interpreter and it worked fine.  What was your specific error?  Did you run the code above exactly (running the second code block before the first)?

Answer (score 6):

## TL;DR

Patch `sys.modules` using `unittest.mock`:

```py
mock.patch.dict(
    sys.modules,
    {'somefakepackage': mock.Mock()},
)
```

## Explanation

Other answers correctly recommend to fix `sys.modules` but **a proper way is to *temporarily patch* it** by using `mock.patch`. It will replace a module *only for the time tests are run* with a fake object that imitates the desired behaviour. And *restore it back* once tests are finished to *not affect other test cases*.

The code in TL;DR section will simply make your missing package not raise `ImportError`. To provide fake package with contents and imitate desired behaviour, initiate `mock.Mock(…)` with proper arguments (e.g. [add attributes via Mock's `**kwargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock)).

## Full code example

The code below temporarily patches `sys.modules` so that it includes `somefakepackage` and makes it importable from the dependent modules without `ImportError`.

```py
import sys
import unittest
from unittest import mock

class SomeTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_smth(self):
        # implement your testing logic, for example:
        self.assertEqual(
            123,
            somefakepackage_dependent.some_func(),
        )

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):  # called once before all the tests
        # define what to patch sys.modules with
        cls._modules_patcher = mock.patch.dict(
            sys.modules,
            {'somefakepackage': mock.Mock()},
        )
        # actually patch it
        cls._modules_patcher.start()
        # make the package globally visible and import it,
        #   just like if you have imported it in a usual way
        #   placing import statement at the top of the file,
        #   but relying on a patched dependency
        global somefakepackage_dependent
        import somefakepackage_dependent

    @classmethod  # called once after all tests
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # restore initial sys.modules state back
        cls._modules_patcher.stop()
```

To read more about `setUpClass`/`tearDownClass` methods, [see `unittest` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass).

`unittest`'s built-in `mock` subpackage is actually a very powerful tool. [Dive deeper into its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 5):

You could fake it with a class which behaves like `somethingfake`:

```
try:
    from somefakepackage.morefakestuff import somethingfake
except ImportError:
    class somethingfake(object):
         # define what you'd expect of somethingfake, e.g.:
         @staticmethod
         def somefunc():
             ...
         somefield = ...
```