# synthesized submodule: from A import B (ok) vs. import A.B (error)?

Tags: python, boost-python, python-module, synthetic

I have a module `modA`, which contains a synthesized submodule `modB` (created with `PyModule_New`); now importing the module:

1. `from modA import modB` it is OK
2. `import modA.modB` fails.

What am I missing?

- modA.cpp (using `boost::python`, but it would be very likely the same with pure c-API of python):

  ```
  #include<boost/python.hpp>
  namespace py=boost::python;

  BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(modA){
     py::object modB=py::object(py::handle<>(PyModule_New("modB")));
     modB.attr("__file__")="<synthetic>";
     py::scope().attr("modB")=modB;
  };
  ```
- compile with (g++ instead of clang++ works the same)

  ```
  clang++ -o modA.so modA.cpp -fPIC -shared  -lboost_python `pkg-config python --cflags --libs`
  ```
- test.py:

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path.append('.')
  from modA import modB
  import modA.modB
  ```
- `python test.py` (note the first import is just fine, it is the second one which fails):

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
      import modA.modB
  ImportError: No module named modB
  ```

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I just did that, thanks for suggestion. Have to wait 2 days to accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5122529/761090), I found the solution, which consists in `sys.modules['modA.modB']=modB`, but written in c++ in the module initialization function:

```
#include<boost/python.hpp>
namespace py=boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(modA){
   py::object modB=py::object(py::handle<>(PyModule_New("modA.modB")));
   modB.attr("__file__")="<synthetic>";
   py::scope().attr("modB")=modB;

   // this was the missing piece: sys.modules['modA.modB']=modB
   py::extract<py::dict>(py::getattr(py::import("sys"),"modules"))()["modA.modB"]=modB;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pattern I use, hopefully it improves previous answers...

module.h:

```
...
#define STR(str) #str
#define MAKE_SUBMODULE(mod, submod) object submod##_module(handle<>(borrowed(PyImport_AddModule(STR(mod.submod)))));\
scope().attr(STR(submod)) = submod##_module;\
scope submod##_scope = submod##_module;\
...
export_submodule();
...
```

module.cpp:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(modulename)
{
    export_submodule();
}
```

submodule.cpp:

```
export_submodule()
{
    // create submodule
    MAKE_SUBMODULE(modulename, submodulename)

    // all code below is now in submodule's scope
    ...
}
```

The "generated" code looks like this:

```
object submodulename_module(handle<>(borrowed(PyImport_AddModule("modulename.submodulename"))));
scope().attr("submodulename") = submodulename_module;
scope submodulename_scope = submodulename_module;
```

It looks similar to eudoxos answer, but the differencs seems to be in detail: Instead of `PyImportNew()` I use `PyImportAdd()`. Therefor I don't need the last line to get the `from module.submodule import *` statement working.

Answer (score 0):

`modB` is not a file (i.e. a module), but some object in `modA`, hence it cannot be imported.

You may want to see [Python's modules docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: `modB` is a module, it just happens to be created on the fly.

Comment: I don't understand. Please specify - is `modB` a file or not?

Comment: No, `modB` is a module object which is being created at runtime.

Comment: `imp.find_module` only searches files, according to documentation. Sorry for confusion, though, I found the solution meanwhile.