# How to install module from Github repo in pyscript?

Tags: python, github, pip, screen-scraping, pyscript

I want to import module from github repo in my pyscript.

From this command link -

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir git+https://github.com/StreamAlpha/tvdatafeed.git
```

So that I can use this code in my pyscript code-

```
from tvDatafeed import TvDatafeed, Interval

username = 'YourTradingViewUsername'
password = 'YourTradingViewPassword'

tv = TvDatafeed(username, password)
```

Comment: Why do you need to install from Github? What's wrong with the PyPI wheel?

Comment: @Selcuk There is no `tvdatafeed` at PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/tvdatafeed/ Github seems to be the only source.

Comment: Sorry, the instructions on the Github page must be inaccurate then.

Answer (score 1):

Check first if this is an import case issue, as reported i [`StreamAlpha/tvdatafeed` issue 94](https://github.com/StreamAlpha/tvdatafeed/issues/94#issuecomment-1335878725):

> You can bypass `pip` by installing via Git using the second command under the installation section.
> If you go this route, you’ll need to change your `import` statement from using `tvdatafeed` to `tvDatafeed`
>
> edit:
>
> ```
> pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir git+https://github.com/StreamAlpha/tvdatafeed.git
> ```

So in your case:

```
from tvDatafeed import tvDatafeed, Interval
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question. Feel free to track it under pyscript's github.
I don't think that's possible because we're currently relying on Pyodide's packaging system and I don't know deep implementation details, but as far as I understand only pure python packages + whatever they ported manually currently works...
I guess one thing you could do is manually create a package yourself.
[Can I "fake" a package (or at least a module) in python for testing purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122465/can-i-fake-a-package-or-at-least-a-module-in-python-for-testing-purposes)
But! It's a lot of work unfortunately.
You can also reach out to the author and let them know it's not working on pypi and/or offer to maintain the package yourself!
Cheers and if still in doubt feel free to join pyscript channels: https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript-collective#resources