# Mock 3rd party website for local development with Python requests library

Tags: python, testing, mocking, python-requests

I'm building a (facebook connected) web server using Flask. Here's an example route

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(request.args.get('access_token'))
    profile = graph.get_object('me')
    return jsonify(profile)
```

This works fine, but it seems bad practice to be continually hitting Facebook servers when I'm doing local dev.

What is the most effective way to re-route the facebook API to mocks or even a mock server? Internally, the `facebook-sdk` library uses `requests` to reach `graph.facebook.com`.

I've seen this question

[python mock Requests and the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753390/python-mock-requests-and-the-response)

and in particular, Dropbox's `responses` library, but it looks like you have to wrap each call in their decorator. It would work well for a unit testing suite, but I'm just interested in doing development against mock data and mock responses.

---

Update: In response to Thomas, I had been thinking about a similar solution. I tried adding:

```
if config_name == 'development':
    print 'monkey'
    import requests
    def mock(*args, **kwargs):
        print args, kwargs
        return {}
    requests.request = mock
```

But that didn't seem to change the behavior of the `facebook-sdk` library.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if `debug` mode is on using `app.config`, and then (if `debug` mode is on), turn your requests into dummy requests. I'm not that familiar with the facebook API, so (unfortunately) I can't write out the dummy code for you.

Comment: Updated in response. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the flask-testing and mock libraries:

```
import requests

from flask.ext.testing import TestCase
from mock import Mock

class TestLogin(TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    requests.request = Mock()
    super(TestLogin, self).setUp()

  def test_it(self):
    resp = self.client.get('/login')
    self.assertEquals('right stuff', resp.data)
```