# Mocking a 500 response when an operation is performed

Tags: python, testing, mocking, python-unittest

This is my test so far:

```
test_500(self):

    client = ClientConfiguration(token=token, url=url)
    client.url = 'https://localhost:1234/v1/' + bucket

    keys = None        

    try:
        get_bucket = json.loads(str(client.get_bucket(bucket)))
        result = get_bucket['result']
    except Exception as e:
        expected_status_code = 500
        failure_message = "Expected status code %s but got status code %s" % (expected_status_code, e)
        self.assertEquals(e, expected_status_code, failure_message)
```

I need to write a mock that will return a `500` response when the `'https://localhost:1234/v1/' + bucket` url is used. Can this be done with unittest and if so, how or where can I find some documentation on this? I've been through this site, the unittest documentation and Youtube and can't find anythingspecific to what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23914464/7836976) to create my test.

The end result is:

```
@responses.activate
test_500(self):

    responses.add(responses.GET, 'https://localhost:1234/v1/' + bucket,
        json={'error': 'server error'}, status=500)

    client = ClientConfiguration(token=token, url=url)
    client.url = 'https://localhost:1234/v1/'

    keys = None        

    try:
        get_bucket = json.loads(str(client.get_bucket(bucket)))
        result = get_bucket['result']
except Exception as e:
        expected_status_code = 500
        failure_message = "Expected status code %s but got status code %s" % (expected_status_code, e)
        self.assertEquals(e, expected_status_code, failure_message)
```