# Python requests as automated test in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, jenkins-pipeline, pytest

I am relatively inexperienced in the field of Python. I am working with Python Requets and BeautifulSoup. The scripts I write with it are all executable.

Since I don't know anything about Pytest and Unittest, I tried to acquire this knowledge, but I just can't get any further.

I've seen in particular that Python Requests works over Mocks, but I have to say, I'm not sure this is the right way to write tests and include them in a Jenkins pipeline. The goal is to test different http requests of a website, either as a unit test or via Pytest.

What is your opinion?

Is that also possible with Python requests (integration) via mocks?

Do I have to use Pytest or Unittesting?

```
import requests 
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
import pytest 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import postpython

page = requests.get('http://google.de')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://realpython.com/python-testing/):

> You have two types of tests:
>
> 1. **Integration** - An integration test checks that components in your
>      application operate with each other i.e. as a whole end-to-end without any mocks.
> 2. **Unit** - A unit test checks a small
>      component in your application in isolation i.e. mocking all the dependencies for that.

Suppose you have application code that makes a request to an API.

You would use **unit test** to check whether in your application code a request to the API is called or not (without actually making the API request). You would **mock** the behavior of sending request and plant a fake response in your unit test. This is so that you can test your code in **isolation** of the API request/response.

But, if you wanted to actually call the API and get back a real response, then you would use **integration tests**. This allows you to test the application behavior as a whole.

In python, `unittest` and `pytest` are two of many available test runner libraries for writing and managing such **tests**.

If you wanted to mock the requests/response then check this out: [How can I mock requests and the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753390/how-can-i-mock-requests-and-the-response)

From what I understand, you're looking to actually make the request in your Jenkins CI/CD pipeline to the server and see if you get a successful response. This falls into the category of Integration Testing so you wouldn't need to mock anything.

You can do integration tests with both `unittest` or `pytest`.

Here's an example with `pytest`:

```py
import pytest

def test_get_request():
    response = requests.get('http://google.de')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

To run this you can run this command line task in your jenkins pipeline:

```sh
pytest your_test_file.py
```

You can follow this tutorial for more info and introduction on PyTest [here](https://pythontesting.net/framework/pytest/pytest-introduction/).

Comment: Thank´s that helps me!