# Mocking BigQuery Connection in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have the following code in a python file. I have to unit test this file. But in order to do that I need to instantiate the object of the class

```
class BigQuery(metaclass=singleton.Singleton):
    """
    Big Query Class for operations on big query
    Will standardize in future versions.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Used for initializing client
        """
        try:
            self.client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(
                SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON)
        except:
            logging.error("Cannot instantiate bigquery client", exc_info=True)
            raise Exception("Cannot instantiate bigquery client.")
```

The above class also contains other methods that needs to be tested. How will I mock the object for every method without calling bigquery API??

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753390/how-can-i-mock-requests-and-the-response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working. Basically you need to mock the function call to the bigquery client initialization. With the help of `mock.patch` we can mock the client object or the function `from_service_account_json`. The following is the code

```
with patch.object(bigquery.Client, "from_service_account_json") as srv_acc_mock:
            srv_acc_mock.return_value = Mock()

            # do something here....
```

We need to follow the same pattern for GCS client also but change the `bigquery.Client` to `storage.Client` by importing the right modules.

Comment: Can you help with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77241495/how-to-mock-google-bigquery-client-for-unittests-in-pytests

Comment: You can also add the entire code snippet you have it working , that would be a great help!

Answer (score 5):

While your accepted solution could work, it'll be more complete and robust to mock all of `bigquery.Client`. This will prevent implementation changes from breaking the mock, and it makes it easy to set return values:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('google.cloud.bigquery.Client', autospec=True)
def my_test(mock_bigquery): 
  mock_bigquery().query.return_value = ...
```

Comment: Can you help with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77241495/how-to-mock-google-bigquery-client-for-unittests-in-pytests