# Why does my mocking of an URL with requests not work?

Tags: python, python-requests, mocking, python-unittest

I tried to mock a specific URL as shown in this example:
[How can I mock requests and the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753390/how-can-i-mock-requests-and-the-response)
to test my own function:

```
class URLStatus():
  @staticmethod
  def check(url, redirects):
    try:
      session = requests.Session()
      session.max_redirects = redirects
      urlcheck = session.get(url)
      return urlcheck.status_code
```

The issue is that it never takes the mocked url, but instead only takes real ones.

```
import requests

from unittest import TestCase, mock
from unittest.mock import patch

from lib.checks.url_status import URLStatus


def mocked_requests_get(*args, **kwargs):
  class MockResponse:
    def __init__(self, json_data, status_code):
      self.json_data = json_data
      self.status_code = status_code

    def json(self):
      return self.json_data

  if args[0] == 'http://someurl.com/test.json':
    return MockResponse({"key1": "value1"}, 200)
  elif args[0] == 'http://someotherurl.com/anothertest.json':
    return MockResponse({"key2": "value2"}, 200)

  return MockResponse(None, 404)

class URLStatusTestCase(TestCase):

  @mock.patch('lib.checks.url_status.requests.get', side_effect=mocked_requests_get)
  def test_check(self, mock_get):

    url_status = URLStatus()
    test_data = url_status.check('http://someurl.com/test.json', 5)
    self.assertEqual(test_data, 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

This one, for example, fails because it sees 'http://someurl.com/test.json' as a 404, not a 200. I have no idea why this is happening.

How do I make it take the mocked URL?

Comment: You are mocking `requests.get`; your function calls `session.get`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mocking the wrong function. `requests.get` is a convenience function that creates its own, one-use `Session`, then uses its `get` method to provide the result. Your `check` method is using its *own* `Session` object; you need to at least mock that object's `get` method.

Given that you aren't reusing this session elsewhere, it would probably be simplest to change *its* implementation to take advantage of `requests.get`:

```
class URLStatus():
    @staticmethod
    def check(url, redirects):
        return requests.get(url, max_redirects=redirects).status_code
```