# Mocking multiple API calls in my class and writing a test

Tags: python, testing, python-requests, python-unittest

So, I am trying to mock some API's in my class, the code looks something like this.

```
import requests
class myclass:
  def A(self, data):
    response = requests.get("some_url", params)
    if response.data["has_value"]:
      new_response = requests.get("some_url", params)
      **do some validation on data recieved**
  def B(self, data):
    response = requests.get("some_url", params)
    **do some validation on data recieved**
  def _run(self):
    **some code**
    self.A(data)
    self.B(data)

m = myclass()
m.run()
```

I am trying to test for these and need some help with it. while doing validations we change some fields in data, and I have to verify if the data is correct. how can this be done?
Thank you.

Comment: Which will be the functions under test? What do you want to mock? Why do you want to mock it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: the run function will be under test. I want to mock the api's. I want to mock the apis inorder to reduce the api usage. i have tried using the mock module but i am not sure how. to mock multiple get calls.

Comment: I see! You want to mock `requests.get`? See this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28507806/384954 The most important thing here is `@mock.patch('requests.get', side_effect=mocked_requests_get)` as a decorator on your _test function_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mock requests and the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753390/how-can-i-mock-requests-and-the-response)

Comment: how will the side effect work in my case? in `stackoverflow.com/a/28507806/384954` we are providing urls to fetchJson function but how will i distinguish between the get requests?

Comment: Notice that inside `mocked_requests_get` the urls are being distinguished, and different fake responses are sent based on that. `@mock.patch` is patching all instances of `requests.get` in the entire call stack for the test.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Was able to do what i intended.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution using `unittest` package of `Python 3.7.5`:

`myclass.py`:

```py
import requests


class MyClass:
    def A(self, data):
        params = None
        response = requests.get("some_url", params)
        if response.data["has_value"]:
            new_response = requests.get("some_url", params)
            print(new_response)

    def B(self, data):
        params = None
        response = requests.get("some_url", params)

    def _run(self):
        data = {}
        self.A(data)
        self.B(data)
```

`test_myclass.py`:

```py
import unittest
from myclass import MyClass, requests
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from collections import namedtuple


class testMyClass(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('builtins.print')
    @patch.object(requests, 'get')
    def test_A(self, mocked_get, mocked_print):
        Response = namedtuple('Response', ['data'])
        response = Response(data={'has_value': True})
        mocked_get.side_effect = [response, 'new response']
        myclass = MyClass()
        data = {}
        myclass.A(data)
        mocked_get.assert_called_with('some_url', None)
        self.assertEqual(mocked_get.call_count, 2)
        mocked_print.assert_called_with('new response')

    def test_B(self):
        # same as test_A, you can do it.
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

    def test__run(self):
        myclass = MyClass()
        myclass.A = MagicMock()
        myclass.B = MagicMock()
        myclass._run()
        myclass.A.assert_called_with({})
        myclass.B.assert_called_with({})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.002s

OK
Name                                         Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/60910413/myclass.py           15      2    87%   13-14
src/stackoverflow/60910413/test_myclass.py      27      0   100%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                           42      2    95%
```