# how to mock a response of a requests in Python

Tags: python, python-3.7

Here is the code below:

```
response = requests.get("xyx@.com", stream=True)
data = response.raw.read()
```

i want to mock "response.raw.read()" , i know several options for mocking requests.get but i need to mock the 2nd line of code.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mock requests and the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753390/how-can-i-mock-requests-and-the-response)

Comment: i want to mock "response.raw.read()" this code