# Python3 mock response object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one function where I am calling API to post get the resource. Since my function does not return anything then its tough to write unit test for failure scenario. Here I want to force `request.get()` to return different HTTP status code.

Is there anyway  to mock my  function to  return desired status code?

**foo.py**

```py
def getData():
    response = requests.get(run_task_status_url, headers=iics_job_header)
    logging.debug(f"Activity Monitor API response: {response.json()}")

    if 200 == response.status_code:
        print("success")
    else 401  == response.status_code:
        print("401")
```

Comment: see https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/response.html

Comment: your function logic is also faulty, you log `response.json` but that is not guaranteed to be returned for anything other than a `200`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mock requests and the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753390/how-can-i-mock-requests-and-the-response)

Comment: If you are using pytest frame work there is an example in the docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html#monkeypatching-returned-objects-building-mock-classes