# How to mock external API call inside a different request function DRF, python

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mocking, python-unittest, patch

In ViewSet in my DRF project:
Let's say I have a post request in which I firstly get data from external api with requests.get, and then I serialize and return it as should be in post request. I am writing unittest with django unittest and I want to mock external api call. This is my first time with mock and I can't find such a case.

To sum up:

- I have post function which gets data from external api if user hasn't passed something.
- I want to mock result of requests.get but I don't know how to implement it to test for post function

I don't know If It would help you to get code snippets or my story is enough. If so, I can add it just let me know.

Comment: Yes some snippets would help and also can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mock requests and the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753390/how-can-i-mock-requests-and-the-response)

Answer (score 0):

You can use python unittest mock. Here is the official document: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html