# Testing: do not wait for the data from the requests.get function, but get the Response object

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest

I have a class like this (simplified):

```
class DataGainer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_url = None
    
    def get_data(self, url):
        response = requests.get(url) # very long request
        self.last_url = response.url
        ...
```

As a test I'd like to make sure, that after the request I have correct url in the last_url property. So I do not care, what data will be returned by get, but I need to have Response object with url. That is why I can't use mock. Maybe there is a way to pass timeout argument somehow?

My test so far looks this way (simplified):

```
def test_last_url():
    url = 'some.url'
    dg = DataGainer()
    dg.get_data(url)
    assert dg.last_url == url
```

This test is very slow, because of the get request. How can I make it faster?

P.s.: I'd like to check last_url because I process it somehow

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753390/how-can-i-mock-requests-and-the-response) help at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, all the answers offer mocking the response without actual sending the request. The responses library gives an opportunity to pass the request through, but I can't modify it to set timeout of 1ms, for example