# how to write pytest for attribute service call using monkey patch was called?

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I have one function for calling attribute service call. Now I want to write pytest for that using monkey patch. How to write test code for this monkey patch was called?

```
def attr_service_call(attr_url):
    PARAMS = {'username':'username', 'password':'password'}
    resp = requests.get(attr_url, params=PARAMS, timeout= 30)
    resp_json = resp.json()
    resturn resp_json
```

How to write pytest for above code and and attr service call was called using monkey patching. Help me to write pytest for this. Thanks

Comment: Which part of the function (or the whole thing) do you want to monkeypatch?

Comment: @Tzane I need to test for request response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mock requests and the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753390/how-can-i-mock-requests-and-the-response)

Comment: @Laurent Yes, actually I worked on that. I resolved that. Thank you