# How to create unit tests for a FastAPI endpoint that makes request to another endpoint?

Tags: python, unit-testing, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app that makes requests to other endpoint within a function that handles a particular request.

How can I build unit tests for this endpoint using `fastapi.testclient.TestClient`?

```
import fastapi
import requests
import os

app = fastapi.FastAPI()

# in production this will be a k8s service to allow for 
# automatic scaling and load balancing.
# The default value works when the app is run using uvicorn
service_host = os.environ.get('SERVICE_HOST', 'localhost:8000')

@app.post('/spawner')
def spawn():
    # an endpoint that makes multiple requests to set of worker endpoints
    for i in range(4):
         url = 'http://'+service_host+f'/create/{i}'
         requests.post(url)
    return {'msg': 'spawned the creation/update of 4 resources'}

@app.post('/create/{index}')
def worker(index: int):
    # an endpoint that does the actual work of creating/updating the resource
    return {'msg': f'Created/updated resource {index}'}
```

Comment: Not in response to your test client answer, but just as a performance improvement: you can call an endpoint in the same app by just calling the endpoint function rather than posting to your own service. This way, you forgo all the network calls.

Comment: Additionally; it would actually solve your test client question, come to think of it

Answer (score 3):

How to write the unit tests depends on what specifically you want to be checking.

For example, from your sample code, if you just want to check that your `/spawner` endpoint properly calls your `/create` endpoint a certain number of times, you can use Python's [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) to patch the `requests.post` call such that it doesn't make the actual call, but you can inspect the call it would have made. (See [How can I mock requests and the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15753390/2745495) for examples on how to mock external calls made by the `requests` library.)

You still use [FastAPI's `TestClient`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/) to make the call to your endpoint, but while the `.post` call is patched:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app

from unittest.mock import patch

def test_spawn():
    client = TestClient(app)
    mocked_response = requests.Response()
    mocked_response.status_code = 200

    with patch("requests.post", return_value=mocked_response) as mocked_request:
        response = client.post("/spawner")

    # Expect that the requests.post was called 4 times
    # and it called the /create/{index} endpoint
    assert mocked_request.call_count == 4
    called_urls = [call.args[0] for call in mocked_request.call_args_list]
    assert called_urls[0].endswith("/create/0")
    assert called_urls[1].endswith("/create/1")
    assert called_urls[2].endswith("/create/2")
    assert called_urls[3].endswith("/create/3")

    # Expect to get the msg
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"msg": "spawned the creation/update of 4 resources"}
```

`patch` returns a [`Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) object, which has attributes like [`call_count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_count) telling you how many times the `requests.post` function was called and a [`call_args_list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list) storing the arguments for each call to `requests.post`. Then, your test can also assert that if everything behaved as expected, then it should return the expected response.

Now, going back to what I said, the usefulness of this test largely depends on what *specifically* are you hoping to gain from writing the tests. One problem with this test is that it isn't strictly black-box testing, because the test "knows" how the endpoint is supposed to work internally. If the point is to make sure, for example, that calling `/spawner` with some query parameter `?count=N` results in `N` number of spawned resources, then *maybe* this kind of test is useful.

Another thing, this kind of test makes sense if you are making *actual* external calls to *some other API*, and not to your *own* endpoint. [User JarroVGit mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74831663/create-unit-test-for-fastapi-endpoint-that-makes-request-to-another-endpoint#comment132065020_74831663) that a better implementation would be, instead of making a POST request, you can refactor `/spawner` to call the endpoint function directly *and* pass the `/create` response:

```
@app.post("/spawner")
def spawn():
    # an endpoint that makes multiple requests to set of worker endpoints
    results = [worker(i) for i in range(4)]
    return {
        "msg": "spawned the creation/update of 4 resources",
        "results": results,
    }

@app.post("/create/{index}")
def worker(index: int):
    # an endpoint that does the actual work of creating/updating the resource
    worker_inst.create(index)
    return {"msg": f"Created/updated resource {index}"}
```

The test can be made simpler by patching whatever is in `/create` to *not* create the actual resources (here, I'm assuming some sort of a `worker_inst.create(index)` that does the actual creation):

```
def test_spawn():
    client = TestClient(app)

    # Patch the actual create/update resources to *not* create anything
    with patch.object(WorkerInst, "create"):
        response = client.post("/spawner")

    # Expect to get the msg
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {
        "msg": "spawned the creation/update of 4 resources",
        "results": [
            {"msg": "Created/updated resource 0"},
            {"msg": "Created/updated resource 1"},
            {"msg": "Created/updated resource 2"},
            {"msg": "Created/updated resource 3"},
        ],
    }
```

I don't know what kind of "resources" your app is creating, but you can possibly convert that unit test into a more useful integration test, by removing the `patch`-ing of `worker` and just letting the worker create the resources, then let the test assert that 1) the correct resources were created, and 2) the `/spawner` endpoint returned the expected response. Again, depends on what "resources" is and the purpose of your tests.