# how to mock in python API testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm trying to mock a sample function below. Somehow I'm getting error.
For example,
I've a class as below `myclass.py`:

```
import os, requests

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, login_url):
        self.username = os.environ.get('username')
        self.password = os.environ.get('password')
        self.login_url = login_url
        self.auth_credentials = {
            'name': self.username,
            'password': self.password
        }

    def get_access_token(self):
        token = ""
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
        response = requests.post(self.login_url, json=self.auth_credentials, headers=headers, verify=False)
        access_token = response.json().get('access_token')
        return access_token
```

Now, I'm having unit-test as below `unit_test.py`, which is actually throwing an error:

```
import os
import requests
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch, MagicMock
import MyClass

class TestModule(unittest.TestCase):
    # @patch('MyClass.get_access_token')
    def test_execute(self):
        # Test/Mock API:
        _obj = MyClass(login_url="https://www.my-website.com/login/")

        mock_access_token = "abc123def456ghi789"
        with patch('MyClass.get_access_token') as _access:
            _access.return_value.status_code = 200
            _access.return_value.json.return_value = mock_access_token
            response = _obj.get_access_token()
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
            self.assertEqual(response, mock_access_token)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

So, what am I missing here in `unit_test.py` ?

Comment: Please also add the error to your question.

Comment: The title doesn't really fit the question, you should update it.

Comment: Actually, there is no need for tedious copy-pasting of errors into the question. Since a full MWE is provided, anyone can run the code themselves and see what error they get. You would need to run the code anyway to troubleshoot it and give a good answer. So while it sucks that curious passers-by (who are not able to run Python code) will be left hanging, this does not actually prevent someone knowledgeable from producing an answer.

Comment: @Dommondke while this is an example of a very well formulated question, the error is still valuable. For example, if the error was an `ImportError`, changing the test wouldn't have any effect. Including the error in the question helps narrowing down the problem and prevents unnecessary feedback cycles. Also, copy-pasting the error takes ~10 seconds. Setting up an environment, installing all dependencies, copying and running the code takes longer.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I've fixed it by this.
It's working now.

```
import os
import requests
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from myclass import MyClass

class TestModule(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_execute(self):
        # Test/Mock API:
        _obj = MyClass(login_url="https://www.my-website.com/login/")

        mock_access_token = "abc123def456ghi789"
        with patch('myclass.MyClass.get_access_token') as mock_get_access_token:
            mock_get_access_token.return_value = mock_access_token
            response = _obj.get_access_token()
            self.assertEqual(response, mock_access_token)
            print("Done")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: This test is meaningless. You could as well `assert True`. Please read @Dommondke's answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this line, you are replacing `MyClass.get_access_token` with a `MagicMock` instance:

```
with patch('MyClass.get_access_token') as _access:
```

This means it will start returning another `MagicMock` everytime you call some methods. It will also disregard everything inside your `get_access_token` method (you replaced it with a mock, remember?). However, your test code is still attempting to test the internal logic of this method, like accessing methods of the response.

What you really want to mock here is the network request, not your method. Your method itself doesn't have any side effects, libraries it calls do. So you need to mock the libraries, in this case `requests`. You need to implement appropriate mocks such that when `get_access_token` calls `requests.post`, instead of actually making a POST request, it will return a mock response with the appropriate members (like `json()`).

Since `requests` is a bit complex, you might find this helpful: [How can I mock requests and the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15753390/19438577)

---

Your code also has a bunch of import errors (`ModuleNotFoundError`). I won't go into detail on these because it should be a separate question. When these are fixed, the test start failing (ie. not crashing) on this line:

```
self.assertEqual(response, mock_access_token)
```

This is because `response` is a `MagicMock` instance and `mock_access_token` is a string, so obviously they cannot be equal. When you rewrite this as:

```
self.assertEqual(response.json(), mock_access_token)
```

It passes. However, I suspect that the test is not testing what you think it is, so I'd recommend introducing some bugs into the method and seeing if the test catches them. Like I said, you probably want to rewrite your whole unit test so that it's mocking `requests` instead of your method.