# How do I mock a file object with a set size?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have a function that raises an exception if the size of a file is too big (> 1MB). I would like to test this function without using a real image. I know it is possible to mock file objects with mock_open but how do I give this fake file a size?

Here is the function I want to test:

```
def _check_image_size(img_path):
    megabyte = 1048576

    if os.path.getsize(img_path) > megabyte:
        raise ValueError("Image must be less than or equal to 1MB in size.")
```

So just to reiterate the question in a different way: how to I test this function without using a real file greater than 1MB in size?

P.S. Should I even write a test for this function? I am very much a new developer who doesn't have much experience. Am I going overboard by wanting to test this?

Comment: Near duplicate, but at least applicable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672138/how-do-i-mock-the-filesystem-in-python-unit-tests. This covers most of what is in (and what I considered adding to) my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simpler to mock the function itself.

```
with mock.patch('os.path.getsize', return_value=2*1024*1024)
    try:
        _check_image_size("any arbitrary string")
    except ValueError:
        print "Successfully raised ValueError"
    else:
        print "Did not raise ValueError"
```

Or, without using the `mock` library (or something similar), monkey patch the function directly.

```
import os.path

os.path.getsize = lambda path: return 2*1024*1024
try:
    _check_image_size("any arbitrary string")
except ValueError:
    print "Successfully raised ValueError"
else:
    print "Did not raise ValueError"
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew I had to mock something but I was looking at the wrong thing to mock. Mocking the os.path.getsize worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing this, you should mock `os.path.getsize` instead - the file object mocked with `unittest.mock` provides a `read` method, maybe `write`, `close` and other file object specific functions - but this function makes a system `stat` call to an actual file on the filesystem: the mocked file-object can't be "seen" on the filesystem.

So, the thing to do is instead to trust `os.path.getsize` works, and mock its return values to "True" and "False" to write the tests you want.

Answer (score 0):

mock is your friend

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import os

def _check_image_size(img_path):
    megabyte = 1048576

    if os.path.getsize(img_path) > megabyte:
        raise ValueError("Image must be less than or equal to 1MB in size.")

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("os.path.getsize")
    def test_getsize(self, getsize):
        getsize.return_value =  1024 ** 2 + 4

        self.assertRaises(ValueError,lambda: _check_image_size("some path to a big* file"))
```

I think its OK to test a function like this one.