# How to test working with directories using pathlib

Tags: python, unit-testing, pathlib

I have a function that searches for .json files in directory recursively. It uses `pathlib`.

```
def search(where: Path) -> List[Path]: ...
```

I want to unit test it, so I need to a way create fake `Path` object with children, so that `fake_path.iterdir()` and `fake_path.resolve()` would work.

Ideally, I want this:

```
topdir = FakePath()
subdir1 = FakePath()
subdir1.add_children(Path('file1'), Path('file2'))
topdir.add_children(subdir1)

for dir in topdir.iterdir():
    for file in dir.iterdir():
        print(file.name)

>> file1
>> file2
```

and have it behave like normal Path object after that.

Is there a library that does that? Or can `pathlib` do what I want, and I'm just blind?

(I know I can just create temp files, but I'd prefer to not have any IO in unit tests.)

Comment: I'd say: don't. `pathlib` is already well tested and proven. I don't see what `search()` function adds, especially seeing that its interface is identical to the underlying pathlib call (you *are* using `glob()`, right?)

Comment: In this particular case, I think you're right. But with more complex logic, like if want to move files to directories based on part of a name of a file, I'd want to test that. 

(Shame on me, I used `chain(*(p.iterdir() for p in mydir.iterdir()))` with `filter` instead of `glob` .)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672138/how-do-i-mock-the-filesystem-in-python-unit-tests

Comment: @Gokul Thanks! Guess I should just get better at googling (: Looks like `pyfakefs` from second answer is exactly what I need.

Comment: Use `glob.glob("**/*.json", recursive=True)`, since it's from stdlib, there's no need to test it :)