# Mocking urllib2.urlopen().read() for different responses

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to mock the urllib2.urlopen library in a way that I should get different responses for different urls I pass into the function.

The way I am doing it in my test file now is  like this

```
@patch(othermodule.urllib2.urlopen)
def mytest(self, mock_of_urllib2_urllopen):
    a = Mock()
    a.read.side_effect = ["response1", "response2"]
    mock_of_urllib2_urlopen.return_value = a
    othermodule.function_to_be_tested()   #this is the function which uses urllib2.urlopen.read
```

I expect the the othermodule.function_to_be_tested to get the value "response1" on first call and "response2" on second call which is what side_effect will do

but the othermodule.function_to_be_tested() receives

```
<MagicMock name='urlopen().read()' id='216621051472'>
```

and not the actual response. Please suggest where I am going wrong or an easier way to do this.

Comment: You can just patch `@patch(urllib2.urlopen)` directly..

Comment: I am trying to patch the copy which is imported in my other module. I guess thats the way it's supposed to be done

Comment: I would personally just redesign my code to not be hardcoded to use `urllib.urlopen` at all; e.g. it would be calling `self.urlopen_fn` whose default value is `urllib.urlopen` but which you can just set to `your_mock_urlopen` during testing; it can even be a module-level parameter you can set from the outside.

Comment: You imported `urllib2`, so both `othermodule.urllib2.urlopen` and `urllib2.urlopen` refer to the *exact same function object*.

Comment: @ErikAllik: mock *should* make this easy.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yeah, I know, but I think designing your code to not need such patch-mocking make it better overall.

Comment: I don't agree; you still need to use a standard library call *somewhere* at some point.

Comment: See also: [How can one mock/stub python module like urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295438/562769)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The argument to `patch` needs to be a description of the *location* of the object, not the object *itself*. So your problem looks like it may just be that you need to stringify your argument to `patch`.

Just for completeness, though, here's a fully working example. First, our module under test:

```
# mod_a.py
import urllib2

def myfunc():
    opened_url = urllib2.urlopen()
    return opened_url.read()
```

Now, set up our test:

```
# test.py
from mock import patch, Mock
import mod_a

@patch('mod_a.urllib2.urlopen')
def mytest(mock_urlopen):
    a = Mock()
    a.read.side_effect = ['resp1', 'resp2']
    mock_urlopen.return_value = a
    res = mod_a.myfunc()
    print res
    assert res == 'resp1'

    res = mod_a.myfunc()
    print res
    assert res == 'resp2'

mytest()
```

Running the test from the shell:

```
$ python test.py
resp1
resp2
```

**Edit**: Whoops, initially included the original mistake. (Was testing to verify how it was broken.) Code should be fixed now.